# vb.net uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier _dopostback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

in my code there is a button called "New Quote". when i click on it will ask are you sure you want to continue a jquery alert.

On every page load this line executed

```
Me.ibtnNewQuote3.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('" & Are you sure? & "')")
```

in my on click method i can see two function if i remove one function it works but i need two of them.

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to start a new quote?') __doPostBack('ctl00$mainContent$ibtnNewQuote3','')"
```

Comment: confrim() returns true, or false - and is NOT jQuery - but only pure javascript. Are you looking to replace the confirm dialog with say a jQuery.UI dialog? Or you want a extra JavaScript command after the confirm, you can do this, but you have to conditional run that 2nd JavaScript command based on the first confirm(), else that 2nd command will always run - and no return true (or false) to control the server side event click will run. So, it not clear if you attempting (wanting) to dump the confirm and use say a jQuery.ui dialog, or are you just wondering where _dopostback came from?

Comment: That first line is not valid VB code.